# How to Get the content of html tag in c#

Tags: c#, html, getelementsbytagname

I want to get the content in the "p" tag from HTML  document

```
<div id=123>
  <div class="abc">

       <div class="xyz">
         <p>
             this is the contents
         </p>
```

I use

```
dynamic document = webControl1.ExecuteJavascriptWithResult("document");
var p = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
```

but it doesn't work

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This works

```
dynamic document = webControl1.ExecuteJavascriptWithResult("document");
var p = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
  for (int i = 0; i < p.length; i++)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(p[i].innerText) ;

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

`var p = document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0].innerHTML;`